# Spring Security: Authenticate against multiple LDAP servers & DAO-based authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm working on a Springboot application which has a requirement to support authentication locally (through a DAO-based provider) and through multiple LDAP servers (administratively configured, stored in the database).

With a single LDAP provider my configure method looks like:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchBase(userSearchBase)
        .groupSearchBase(groupSearchBase)
        .userSearchFilter(userSearchFilter)
        .userDetailsContextMapper(new DaoUserDetailsContextMapper())
        .contextSource().url(url+"/"+base)
        .managerPassword(managerPassword)
        .managerDn(managerDn);
  }
```

Through other similar posts it appears this could be accomplished through creating multiple LDAP providers, and Spring security will cycle through each one until a successful login is found.  I have the associated LDAP configuration record associated as a foreign key on the User table.

Is there a more efficient way to try the specific LDAP endpoint associated with the user, or is it best to let Spring iterate through the available providers?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Good day, did you solve this? I have the similar task.

Answer (score 0):

after long search in my way, I found something interesting about how Spring Security authentification works (there is a video : https://youtu.be/caCJAJC41Rk?t=781)

After that, you can use the system that Spring has implemented which is to override the `supports(class<?> authenticationClass)` method. This method works as "Can you, AuthenticationProvider, manage this kind of AuthenticationClass ?" if true, the provider will try to authenticate the user, if not, never execute any tasks.

In that way, you can implement your own `CustomAuthentificationProvider`  which implements the `AuthenticationProvider` interface.

```
public class LocalUserAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserRepository;

    public LocalUserAuthenticationProvider(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        /*my jobs*/
        throws new AuthenticationException("Cannot authenticate");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return MyUsernameAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }
}
```

with your own AuthenticationToken

```
public class StringUsernameAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {

    public StringUsernameAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(principal, credentials);
    }

    public StringUsernameAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
    }
}
```

Actually I don't find any solutions with the LDAP authentication in the AuthenticationManagerBuilder implemented by Spring Security (ref : https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)

Hope this could help people